# How to increment a user variable in on success and on failure execute sql task in BIDS?

Tags: ssis, bids

I have a simple package in which I'm executing select statement in Execute SQL Task, I want on success of this task my variable @cnt=0 should increase @cnt by one like @cnt=@cnt+1 and in script task i should be able to show it and on failure it should be like @cnt=@cnt-1.

What should I try in precedence constraint, I tried  using this '@CNT==@CNT+1' but it does not increase the value of @cnt on success.

my Expression is
[image: my Expression is]

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Expression Task to set the value of the variable, with precedence constraint of success, and a separate task to reduce it with constraint of failure.
The expression in the precedence constraint itself is to evaluate whether something should happen, not to set the value for a variable.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i'm using BIDS 2008 and i don't know how to do it.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0d65768f-58eb-484a-9697-197d9e5e9607/ssis-2008-expression-task?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: I'm able to increment the value in Data Tools using Expression Task, but now I want the incremented value to be permenant. Like when I execute the package it move from 0 to 1 but second time it gets initialized to 0 again, any way out of this.

Comment: Cool, please can you mark this as the answer to help future people? To make the value permanent you would need to store it somewhere, like in a file or in a database table. Perhaps you'd start the package by loading the value from a table, increment it, and then at the end write back to the table for next time.